# child activity database updates not seen by Parent activity

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity, background

I have an activity with a list / adapter view of customer orders and a second activity for adding a new order. When the add order activity is destroyed, I save the order to an SQLLite DB and return to the activity displaying the customer orders.

But the order just added is not on the list!!

I have tried StartActivityForResult but this does not seem to work.

I have tried to put the List/adapter refresh in onActivityResume, onResume , onRestart but still the order just added is not in the list.

I do not want to separate the saving of the order with the closing of the activity as this is not in keeping with the user experience.

I have saved the number of orders before calling the add order activity and then waiting until the number of orders is greater than the number of orders before calling addOrder activity but this does not flow well.

My question is how best to handle such a situation, as for a user's experience the order added needs to be in the list of orders.

I have another activity where an order can be deleted, and when returning to the parent the order is deleted from the database and thus not on the list. I think this is because the delete is quicker than the insert??

--> Update 2018/04/25

Thank you for your comments. I have made a code example to explain the issue, and in doing so now have a better understand of the execution flow and why I was having the problem.

Below is the code for Activity A which calls Activity B.

```
public class AActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);
    Intent activityB = new Intent(this, BActivity.class   );
    startActivityForResult(activityB,2);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    debug("Resfreshing list from database");
    debug("onActivityResult with result code "+resultCode);
}

void debug(String inmes){Log.e("Activity A:",inmes);}
}

public class BActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);
    ConstraintLayout cL=findViewById(R.id.cl);
    cL.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            debug("onTouch: going to return 7");
            Intent i = new Intent();
            setResult(7, i);
            finish();
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    debug("Inserting record into database");
    debug("onDestroy: going to return 12");
    Intent i = new Intent();
    setResult(12, i);
}

void debug(String inmes){
    Log.e("Activity B:",inmes);}
}
```

The console output below explains what my problem was, as when I hit the back button 0 was being returned, at which point I refreshed my list from the database, but as onDestroy had not yet been executed, the record had not yet been created.

```
Activity A:: Resfreshing list from database.
Activity A:: onActivityResult with result code 0.
Activity B:: Inserting record into database.
Activity B:: onDestroy: going to return 12.
```

Also with the TouchListner the same (obviously):-

```
Activity B:: onTouch: going to return 7.
Activity A:: Resfreshing list from database.
Activity A:: onActivityResult with result code 7.
Activity B:: Inserting record into database.
Activity B:: onDestroy: going to return 12.
```

Conclusion and solution was to override the onBackPressed for the database update.
Below is the updated Activity B;

```
public class BActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);
    ConstraintLayout cL=findViewById(R.id.cl);
    cL.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            debug("onTouch: going to return 7");
            Intent i = new Intent();
            setResult(7, i);
            finish();
            return false;
        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    debug("Inserting record into database");
    debug("onBackPressed: going to return 38");
    Intent i = new Intent();
    setResult(38, i);
    super.onBackPressed();;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    debug("onDestroy: going to return 12");
    Intent i = new Intent();
    setResult(12, i);
}

void debug(String inmes){
    Log.e("Activity B:",inmes);}

}
```

Console output, now with record inserted into database before focus handed back to Activity A:-

```
Activity B:: Inserting record into database.
Activity B:: onBackPressed: going to return 38.
Activity A:: Resfreshing list from database.
Activity A:: onActivityResult with result code 38.
Activity B:: onDestroy: going to return 12.
```

I now know that onDestroy is a background event and should not be used for anything relating to the interactive flow of the application.

Comment: Without code, we have no way of knowing.  When are you saving it to the db?  Are you refetching when the other activity is resumed (the views won't magically update themselves)?  There's dozens of things you could be going well, we can't figure it out by guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will refresh your 1st Activity when you come back after adding orders in 2nd activity. 
Call 2nd activity with StartActivityForResult and Add this code in 1st activity.

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity1.class);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

Before finishing or distroying 2nd activity add these lines

```
    Intent i = new Intent();
    setResult(2, i);
    this.finish();
```